# Laravel artisan script memory footprint

Tags: php, laravel, memory-management, console

In my application (Laravel 5.1) I have different commands which are fairly simple:

- Get ip from RabbitMQ
- Attempt to establish a connection to that ip
- Update DB entry

Since it can take a while to connect to the ip (up to 30sec). I am forced to launch multiple instances of that script. For that I've created console commands which are launched by systemd.

Once I went in production I was quite surprised by the amount of memory which these scripts were consuming. Each script (as reported by **memory_get_usage**) was using about 21mb on startup. Considering that ideally I would need to run about 50-70 on those scripts on the same time it's a quiet big issue for me.

Just as a test I've installed clean Laravel 5.1 project and launched its default `artisan inspire` command, php reported 19mb.

Is it normal for laravel or am I missing something crucial here?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have a queue worker using 25MB on startup :/

Comment: Yeah, I switched to golang :|